# phpseclib\aes not found after composer.phar update using FUELPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

I just up updated composer.phar in my local environment.
Now, I get an error that says

```
Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\AES' not found in /var/www/html/tms2/fuel/core/classes/crypt.php on line 213
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use 1.8/develop?
Recently it has switched to the composer version.
https://github.com/fuel/fuel/commit/87c1a6feb5deaff63dfa2cb561035ea6c51b724b

Check your composer.json and update it, then do composer update again.